# BigQuery returns not found for table

Tags: google-bigquery

I list `BigQuery` tables using:

```
bigquery.tables().list("proj_id", "dataset").setMaxResults(40000L).execute();
```

Then I loop through all tables, getting the data from them to GCS. Some tables appear to be not found when trying to export. Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you give an estimate of the % of tables that fails to export? And have you compared the list of tables that do export and the list of tables that don't export, to see if you can find a pattern?

Comment: consider a) views; b)tables with expiration

Comment: About 10-20% fail. I don't think it's related to theit expiration date as  I have   for example three tables with same creation datetime and one of them doesn't export.  Actually there is no specific pattern. table names have pattern of 'of_%timestamp%_%servername%'

Comment: Can you provide a project_id:job_id of an export job for a table that was successfully listed that was then "not found" during export?

Comment: Thx for guidance. Couldn't reproduce it now. Probably tables expired while I was waiting for previous job completion.